# How to distinguish faces of a polytope from internal sections?

Tags: geometry, polytopes

I have the coordinates of the vertices of a convex polytope in $R^3$ and no other information. I'd like to count the faces of this polytope. I can determine which vertices are coplanar; this will pick out the faces but it will also include internal sections. Is there a way to distinguish between these two?

Comment: Is your polytope convex? If not then what you are asking for is impossible because there exists distinct nonconvex polytopes having the same vertex sets.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes it is known to be convex

Comment: Compute the plane through the coplanar vertices and determine whether the rest of the vertices fall on one side of the plane

Comment: @JoshuaWang: that looks like an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaWang yes this does seem to work in general. I tried it on a number of examples and there seems to be a complication when the polytope faces are triangles and the internal sections are not...I have to give this case more thought but otherwise this looks like a good approach; thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaWang the complication in the last comment is due to an unrelated bug in the code. The approach works in all cases; thanks again.